# mod_rewrite causing too many redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

The `.htaccess` we have in our `document_root` directory is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^posts/1/first-post-title$ /posts/1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/posts/1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/^posts/1/first-post-title$
RewriteRule (.*) posts/1/first-post-title [R=301,L]
```

With just the first `RewriteRule` line, the server correctly redirects. When the other three lines are included and we navigate to "http://localhost/posts/1/first-post-title", Safari is giving an error of:

> Too many redirects occurred trying to open “http://localhost/posts/1/first-post-title”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page.

Comment: External redirects should nearly always be root-relative or absolute or specify an appropriate `RewriteBase`. (This would be a second problem after the redirect loop was resolved.)

Answer (score 1):

Your second line (first RewriteCond rule) is causing a perpetual match. The URL you redirect people to is matching and being redirected again. Drop that rule entirely and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's not simply the first `RewriteCond` that "is causing a perpetual match". The whole second rule (2 conditions and a rewrite) would seem to be flawed.